# What does "-5 User was removed" mean?

Tags: support, reputation

I'm not sure what the reputation message "-5 User was removed" means?

Is it that a user had upvoted my question and was deleted from TeX.SE? That would be funny because (as I remember) I asked two questions and neither the first nor the second has an lower upvote.

I can't find informations to this in the faq or in meta. Can someone please explain this?

Comment: Funny, I just got that message for the first time this afternoon.  It must be new.

Comment: I just got this message today :)

Comment: I got this message today, and was afraid my own account was frozen or 'removed' somehow... whew.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at the mod-only data, and taking a look at the total votes for [A font to typeset proofreader's marks in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65740/a-font-to-typeset-proofreaders-marks-in-latex), I think you are right and a user was expunged. The votes on the question seemed to be 'out by one' when I checked, but then 'sorted themselves out'. That suggests a slight lag somewhere, but does point to your explanation being correct.